# Animation not working on an instantiated prefab (weapon)

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

So i'm working on this project and i'm using it to finally learn how to animate in 3D (taking a small break from coding hehe)
So here i am faced with a problem and i have no idea what i did wrong. First let me explain how everything works.

So the Animator is attached to the player, and the player obviously has a structure of legs arms...etc
everything inside the player is being animated by this animator.
So i have a weapon (a wooden sword) that has it's pivot attached to it's bottom (in case it helps to know)
i'm animating it from that pivot point, which happens to be the parent to which the sword model is a child to.
When i hit the V key the weapon gets instantiated in the player's hand (which is an empty gameobject) and when i press the F key the player attack and activates a trigger in the animation that starts the attack animation.

But the animation is not working properly. more precisely the key frames of the weapon are not being player(as you can see in the video all the rotation axes give the coordinates of 0 0 0 throughout all the animation.
But, ...and this is where the strange things start!... when i manually go through each second to play the animation and see what's happening, you can see that those coordinates start to change and it shows the animation exactly as it's supposed to be. then when i switch back to idle state so that i can start moving around the player normally. when i hit the F key to attack the correct animation is player and no problem happens... Magic? i don't think so... :p

what do you think? what could be causing this problem.
Who's up to solve my riddle  :cool:
Seriously guys what's going on here, i need help.o_O
Thank you all ;)

The Video : [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vwhNg1XOLKc)

Answer (score 0):

In general: You are using an **ALPHA** version [**2019.3.0a4**](https://unity3d.com/de/unity/alpha/2019.3.0a4) ... in short **don't**.

As any alpha version it is like to have some bugs .. especially since you are not even using the latest instance of the alpha which afaik would be [`2019.3.0a12`](https://unity3d.com/de/unity/alpha/2019.3.0a12)!

---

`2019.3.0b1` is actually even already in [BETA state](https://unity3d.com/de/unity/beta/2019.3) a lot of former bugs should be fixed there - but it is still a beta release meaning it is not ready for production.

---

So in general don't even use the beta. Rather stick to the latest stable release version which would now be [`2019.2.3f1`](https://unity3d.com/de/unity/whats-new/2019.2.3)

---

There is not directly listed one relating to the animator not finding a certain object at first and then not animating it .. but as said alpha version are likely to have bugs. Also since it is an instantiated prefab the original instance will be gone .. then **by name** it gets re-assigned by the animator so the main issue might be that you instantiate it in the first place instead of just having it already from the beginning.

You should consider only using the parent/pivot object of that sword and not animate the sword itself at all. Simply spawn it as a child of the animated pivot and you should be fine,